# Getting a null pointer exeception when using scanner to read file

Tags: java, android

I want to read a text file and parse the string until eof..here is a code snippet.. programs.txt is under assets directory

```
    public void insert_programs() throws FileNotFoundException {
    BufferedReader bfr = null;
    try {
        bfr = new BufferedReader(new 
                InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("programs.txt"))); // <-- NPE occurs on that line 

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Scanner pgm = new Scanner(bfr);
    pgm.useDelimiter("*{3}");
    while (pgm.hasNext()) {
        String str = pgm.next();
            process(str);
        }
    }
```

Logs

```
03-14 18:05:34.936: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 18:05:34.936: E/AndroidRuntime(467): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 18:05:34.936: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getAssets(ContextWrapper.java:74)
03-14 18:05:34.936: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at c.theworld.com.nikhil.Database.insert_programs(Database.java:40)
```

Comment: Would you care to put in your code where the NPE occurs? (with a comment like `// <-- NPE occurs on that line`)

Comment: can you provide the output you're seeing?

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: i have added the comment..i have put the logs as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [`ContextWrapper.getAssets()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getAssets%28%29) is throwing the `NullPointerException`.  You are extending `ContextWrapper` (or another class that extends it) and it looks like that has not been initialized properly.  The base [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) within the `ContextWrapper` is null.

Answer (score 1):

add this into your code:

```
bfr = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(this.getAssets().open("programs.txt")));
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like your BufferedReader is going to null. have you tried putting the scanner code inside try catch block. if your program gets IOException then bfr will be null and you'll get NPE.

```
public void insert_programs() throws FileNotFoundException { 
    BufferedReader bfr = null; 
    try { 
        bfr = new BufferedReader(new  
                InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("programs.txt"))); 

Scanner pgm = new Scanner(bfr); 
    pgm.useDelimiter("*{3}"); 
    while (pgm.hasNext()) { 
        String str = pgm.next(); 
            process(str); 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 

    }
```